# Are there any Hosting companies, that offer Geoserver?

Tags: geoserver, hosting

I am working with a non-profit, and we are planning to have a webmap for them. Most of the hosting providers just offer a simple LAMP setup on their Linux option, and if you want to install any software on your own, you need to go for a dedicated server (either real or virtual) which is very expensive for the organisation I am working with.

I have seen that there is a hosting provider for [Mapserver](http://www.mapserverpro.com/) based maps.

Is there any similar provider for Geoserver based maps?

Comment: I'm still trying to find one myself. The problem with AcuGIS is many things do not seem to work right away (pgAdmin can't connect, their cpanel services may throw some javascript errors that render the gui useless, ...). Also, they do not answer e-mails even though they claim to have a 24x7x365 support service. It seems very unreliable so far.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you search with Google for "GeoServer hosting" the very first result offers hosting:

http://www.acugis.com/geoserver-hosting.htm

Answer (score 4):

You might also try:

[Webfaction](http://www.webfaction.com)

They seem to be a hybrid between your standard shared server and a hosted server.  You have the ability to install pretty much any software that you want.  In addition, they will support both the standard LAMP stack, as well as a PostgreSQL backend.

Their pricing is slanted toward a yearly plan, however a monthly plan is only $9.50.

Please note that I am not benefiting financially from this, it is simply my experience with a little research.

Comment: Do you have any "Getting started" information about this? I merged my Geoserver to Tomcat and I have a PostGIS db, I can't figure out how to host it yet.

Comment: You can't use GeoServer here: https://docs.webfaction.com/software/

Answer (score 3):

Saw a tutorial on [running Geoserver on Openshift](http://dubrovsky.posterous.com/geoserver-on-openshift). You might want to consider it, too.

> OpenShift is Red Hat's free, auto-scaling Platform as a Service (PaaS)
>   for applications. As an application platform in the cloud, OpenShift
>   manages the stack so you can focus on your code.

As an added bonus, you can also install the PostGIS spatial database just by adding the Postgresql cartridge. Oh and did I mention that they have a free tier?  Good luck :)

Comment: the cited resource is no longer available

Comment: You can still find the resource on the Wayback Machine: https://web.archive.org/web/20130325010133/http://dubrovsky.posterous.com/geoserver-on-openshift

Answer (score 3):

I'm a bit late on this. You might also try: [mapzone.io](http://mapzone.io/)

It has import, styler, catalog and GeoServer fully integrated. You do not have to deal with server, database or GeoServer directly. It's open source and free for public projects.